# Normal subgroups: is the element $g^{-1}$ of the product $gng^{-1}$ required to be in the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Considering a group such as the integers, how's it possible to have normal subgroups if there are no rational numbers which are the the multiplicative inverse to conjugate with?

In particular the word is usually written as a product $gng^{-1}$ and the integers would have addition defined on it and not multiplying.

I just guess it is okay to do the calculation outside of the group setting yet that is the question.

Comment: When one has a group with the operation written additively (that is, with $a+b$ instead of $ab$), $g^{-1}$ is written as $-g$.

Comment: So the conjugation is in fact calculated through the group's operation & not only by multiplication!? That is just great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of integers $\Bbb Z$ is additive. Its operation is $+$. Thus the conjugation of $\Bbb Z$ by $g\in \Bbb Z$ is given by

$$g+\Bbb Z-g=\{ g+x-g\in \Bbb Z\mid x\in\Bbb Z\}.$$

---

*Warning:* one way to view the group $\Bbb Z$ is via the presentation $\langle a\mid \rangle$; that is, it is the free group on one generator. It is possible, then, to write $g\Bbb Z g^{-1}$, since, in this case, the elements of $\Bbb Z$ are understood as powers of the abstract symbol $a$.